# EloquentJavaScript3rd edition Chapter11

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Кто может объяснить как работает функция sendGossip в 11 главе книги EloquentJavaScript. 
http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html

```js
    import {everywhere} from "./crow-tech";

everywhere(nest => {
  nest.state.gossip = [];
});

function sendGossip(nest, message, exceptFor = null) {
  nest.state.gossip.push(message);
  for (let neighbor of nest.neighbors) {
    if (neighbor == exceptFor) continue;
    request(nest, neighbor, "gossip", message);
  }
}

requestType("gossip", (nest, message, source) => {
  if (nest.state.gossip.includes(message)) return;
  console.log(`${nest.name} received gossip '${
               message}' from ${source}`);
  sendGossip(nest, message, source);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Это что-то вроде подписки. В переменной `next.neighbor` хранится список элементов, которые подписаны на рассылку. Функция `sendGossip` получает сообщение, отправляет его всем элементам, которые подписаны на рассылку. Последний параметр - элемент исключение ( скорее всего тот, кто отправил сообщение )

Comment: Понял. Я еще посмотрел как sendGossip в requestType(nest, message, source) и не пойму. Как происходит перераспределение новых гнезд-соседей (nest.neighbors). При первом вызове source это null и первое гнездо рассылки будет bigOak, оно раскидает в своем окружении сообщения. А вот как потом меняется новое гнездо я не понимаю. Ведь в коненом итоге все знегда получат собщения.

Comment: sendGossip(bigOak, "Kids with airgun in the park");
Butcher Shop received gossip 'Kids with airgun in the park' from Big Oak |
Gilles' Garden received gossip 'Kids with airgun in the park' from Big Oak |
Cow Pasture received gossip 'Kids with airgun in the park' from Big Oak |
Tall Poplar received gossip 'Kids with airgun in the park' from Butcher Shop |
Chateau received gossip 'Kids with airgun in the park' from Butcher Shop |